# I have parsed xml values in node.js server but cannot insert them into mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection, sql-insert

I am trying to parse an xml string and insert the values as attributes of a new record into a table. The code below and the database are on two separate servers and I have successfully selected records from the database before from this server, but I'm having trouble inserting them. Here's my code:

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Connected to MySQL');
 var xmlstring= '<message><username>Robert</username><beaconid>15</beaconid><timeanddate>2014-11-08 10:11:55</timeanddate><entry>false</entry><mindistance>10</mindistandistance></message>';
  var message = new xmldoc.XmlDocument(xmlstring);
 var username;
 var beaconid;
 var timeanddate;
 var entry;
 var mindistance;
 var newrecord = {username: message.childNamed("username").val, beaconid: message.childNamed("beaconid").val, timeanddate: message.childNamed("timeanddate").val,
entry: message.childNamed("entry").val, mindistance: message.childNamed("mindistance").val};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO leavingorentering SET ?', newrecord, function(err, result) {
});
console.log(query.sql);
});
```

When I run the code, it outputs this to the terminal:

```
Connected to MySQL
INSERT INTO leavingorentering SET `username` = 'Robert', `beaconid` = '15', `timeanddate` = '2014-11-08 10:11:55', `entry` = 'false', `mindistance` = '10'
```

However, when I connect to the database from mysql workbench and query it directly the record's not there. I followed [this example](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) for inserting a new record into the database (ctrl+F "paid" if you can't see it) and I used [this parser](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldoc). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to split your problem. Insert 'hand made' values without the xml stuff and see if that works.

Comment: you can add `console.log(err)` in your callback of `connection.query` to see if there is any error message.